# Correct database indexes for sorting query

Tags: c#, sql-server, indexing, linq-to-sql

I have a table:

```
Tutorials
-------
ID
Deleted
CategoryID
DifficultyID
Videos
TotalVisitors
DateCreated
```

On my web page, a query to filter these tutorials is built like follows:

```
var q = db.Tutorials.Where(c => !c.Deleted);

if (Category != null) q = q.Where(c => c.CategoryID == Category.ID);

if (Difficulty != null) q = q.Where(c => c.DifficultyID == Difficulty.ID);

if (OnlyWithVideos) q = q.Where(c => c.Videos > 0);

if (sortMethod != null)
{
    if (sortMethod == SortMethod.MostPopular)
        q = q.OrderByDescending(c => c.TotalVisitors);
    else if (sortMethod == SortMethod.Newest)
        q = q.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCreated);
}
```

I then create the following single index on the table:

```
Deleted ASC
CategoryID ASC    
DifficultyID ASC
Videos ASC
TotalVisitors ASC
DateCreated ASC
```

My questions are:

- Will this index cover all possible queries, or do I need to create an index for each possible search?
- Does the column order of the index matter?
- Does the ASC/DESC order for each column matter?

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not necessary to have an index for each possible query.  In many cases, no index is better.  Also, index performance also depends on the selectivity of the data.  For example, if you have only two possible values, an index isn't going to help very much.
I would suggest looking at the Explain Plain (or Estimation Plan) in the SQL Server Management tool to help you figure out what works best.  Create the index and see how the different queries perform.
Also, column order does matter in a covered index: it should correspond to the order that you are querying the columns.